# How to run Esrally in nohub mode in Centos-7 so it continuously running?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to run Esrally in nohub mode, I'm using putty  to access the centos command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below command works.
Before run it , make sure that there are no existing tally process(to find pgrep ), if so kill them.

```
pgrep esrally
kill -KILL pid
kill {27511..27514}

nohup /usr/local/bin/esrally --track-path=/home/username/samfiles --target-hosts=https://perf-test-es.jupiter-eck.nonprod.wiley.tools --pipeline=benchmark-only --client-options="use_ssl:true,verify_certs:false,basic_auth_user:'username',basic_auth_password:'password',timeout:120" >> rally_stdout.log 2>> rally_stderr.log < /dev/null &
```

Although the stderr.log files are empty it's running.
To see rally logs go to below location and open the rally/log file.
cd /home/username/.rally/logs

[image]